# In which file does laravel decrypt the hashed password with the user provided password using the laravel/ui package?

Tags: php, laravel

I have to implement the logic where I don't want to decrypt or encrypt the password of laravel/UI default package. I have trouble finding where laravel encrypt or decrypts the password. Which files I have to change to make the settings on my way.

Comment: it doesn't decrypt the password, passwords are hashed, they are one way ... the authentication system has User Providers and they will do a hash check with the password

Comment: @lagbox if its hashed then how the hashed password gets verified when user enters its password.

Comment: in what ever User Provider is being used by what every auth configuration you are using

Comment: @lagbox I understood what you said. I am using the default configuration for the password where the provider is by the default user. I want to know where does this hashed password gets checked with the user-provided password.

Comment: in the user provider, if you are using 'eloquent' it uses the `EloquentUserProvider`, if you use 'database' it uses the `DatabaseUserProvider` ... look for the `validateCredentials` method

Comment: yes there is a middleware "RedirectIfAuthenticated" only i have found this line of code there i.e(Auth::guard($guard)->check()).  I think that is checking the hashed password.

Comment: `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider@validateCredentials` `Illuminate\Auth\DatabaseUserProvider@validateCredentials`